# Accessing comments from a credit memo after the event: sales_order_creditmemo_refund

Tags: magento-1.7, orders, creditmemo

I am generating XML which is sent to an external system whenever a Credit Memo is generated. I am using the event `sales_order_creditmemo_refund` which gives me the credit memo and order models (which I am using to generate the appropriate XML)

```
$creditMemo = $observer->getEvent()->getCreditmemo();
$order      = $creditMemo->getOrder();
```

However I am having trouble accessing comments. I can see in `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Creditmemo` there is `getCommentsCollection()` but this is not returning anything.

I am guessing the comments are added to the model at a later stage, should I be using a different event for my observer?

I can see that `Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_order_creditmemo_refund', array($this->_eventObject=>$this));` is located inside the `refund()` method of the same model, but the only other event I can see in the model is `sales_order_creditmemo_cancel`

Comment: have you try: sales_order_creditmemo_save_after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after posting the question I immediately find the answer!

**For anyone else with this issue:**

Checking the `saveAction()` within `Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_CreditmemoController` reveals that the comments are initially only added to the session:

```
$data = $this->getRequest()->getPost('creditmemo');
if (!empty($data['comment_text'])) {
   Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setCommentText($data['comment_text']);
}
```

So from within the observer I can simply call `Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getCommentText()` to return the comment.